# JavaFX: On Mouse Clicked event for parent and its children

Tags: java, javafx

I have a card, that consists of header, body and footer, that can consist of more nodes, like labels, text fields etc.

And I need to catch `on mouse clicked` event ANY TIME when the click occurred **inside the card**, no matter if it was the card itself or one of its children. For now if I click text field, event is not triggered.

```
private StackPane newCard() {
        //card wrapper
        StackPane card = new StackPane();
        VBox cardContent = new VBox();

        JFXDepthManager.setDepth(card, 1);
        //Header
        StackPane header = new StackPane();

        VBox headerContent = new VBox();
        header.getChildren().add(headerContent);
        Label label = new Label("Card title");

        //if I click this text field, event is not triggered
        TextField groupCode = new TextField();

        headerContent.getChildren().addAll(label, groupCode);

        //body
        StackPane body = new StackPane();


        //footer
        StackPane footer = new StackPane();


        cardContent.getChildren().addAll(header, body, footer);
        card.getChildren().add(cardContent);

        //event
        card.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Clicked!"));

        return card;
    }
```

So like in example above, if I click the text field to type something, `"Clicked!"` is not printed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with

```
card.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> System.out.println("Clicked!"));
```

The full mechanism of event handling in JavaFX is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD). In a nutshell, though, an event has a *target*, which in this case is the topmost node that intersects the mouse click. (Intuitively, it's the node on which the user clicks, visually.) So if you click in the text field, the target is the text field. There are two phases of event dispatch: *capturing* and *bubbling*. In the capturing phase, the event is first passed to the root node, then to the child node of the root that is an ancestor of the target, and so on until it reaches the target. During the capturing phase, any event *filters* registered with the appropriate node will be invoked. Once event capture is complete, the bubbling phase starts. In the bubbling phase, the event is first passed to the target node, then to its parent, and so on until it reaches the root node again. During the bubbling phase, event *handlers* registered with the node are invoked.

At any stage of the event processing, a filter or handler may [consume](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) the event. This essentially prevent any further propagation of the event. Some controls have built-in handlers which consume certain events; the text field in your example is one. Consequently, mouse clicks on the text field will not propagate to handlers in parent nodes. Registering an event filter instead of a handler allows the event to be processed by your handler.