# MouseDragEvent not called

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, fxml

I want to be able to read my sliders value, and therefore I use an event listener for my controller class:

```
//Controller class
@FXML
    private Slider gridSlider;

@FXML
    void sliderChange(MouseDragEvent event) {
        int sliderValue = (int) gridSlider.getValue();
        System.out.println(sliderValue);
    }

//My FXML class
<Slider fx:id="gridSlider" blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="203.0" layoutY="84.0" majorTickUnit="8.0" max="32.0" min="8.0" minorTickCount="7" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" onMouseDragReleased="#sliderChange" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="180.0" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" value="8.0">
```

I have tried every single MouseDragEvent and none of the MouseDragEvents has actually been called (like on drag detected which should have been called the moment i start dragging the slider). I found this post, but it didn't solve my problem. 
[JavaFX mouse drag events not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357180/javafx-mouse-drag-events-not-firing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MouseDragEvent` is associated with "full press-drag-release" gestures. Such gestures have to be explicitly started by calling [`Node#startFullDrag()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#startFullDrag()) inside a `DRAG_DETECTED` handler. The [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) of `MouseEvent` provides more information about the different dragging gestures.

With that being said, you probably don't want to use mouse events to know when your `Slider`'s value has changed. It would be listen to one or more properties of your `Slider`. For instance, you can listen or bind to the [`value`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#valueProperty) property to always know the current value. There's also the [`valueChanging`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#valueChangingProperty) property:

> When true, indicates the current value of this Slider is changing. It provides notification that the value is changing. Once the value is computed, it is reset back to false.

That property will be true while the user is dragging the thumb and will become false once the user "drops" the thumb. To listen to the property while using FXML you can inject the `Slider` into the controller and add a listener to it in the `initialize` method:

```java
public class Controller {

  @FXML private Slider slider;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    slider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
      if (!nv) {
        // do something...
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you want, however, you can add such a listener via the FXML file—see [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#collections_and_property_handlers):

```xml
<StackPane ...>
  <Slider onValueChangingChange="#handleValueChangingChange"/>
</StackPane>
```

```java
public class Controller {

  @FXML
  private void handleValueChangingChange(ObservableValue<Boolean> obs, Boolean ov, Boolean nv) {
    if (!nv) {
      // Do something...
    }
  }
}
```

***Note:** My examples use the `valueChanging` property because that would seem to provide the behavior you want, as you were trying to listen to when the mouse was released. However, the value can be changed programmatically which, as far as I know, does not affect the `valueChanging` property. Thus, if you want to always know the current value, you need to observe the `value` property.*